# Vscode suggest wrong latest version of packages

Tags: visual-studio-code, package.json

I tried to update my package to the latest version by the vscode suggestion (directly in packges.json), but the vscode suggestion seems to differ from npm released ones, is there something I should change in settings (e.g. npm registry) to fix it?

```json
// This is the latest version from npmjs.com/package/react-scripts
"react-scripts": "4.0.3", 

// This is the next version which vscode suggest
"react-scripts": "5.0.0-next.47",
```

```json
// This is the latest version that npm suggest
"react-dom": "17.0.2",

// Vsode suggest the experimental version
"react-dom": "^0.0.0-experimental-6c3dcc7a4-20211027",
```